# Множина чи однина щодо фруктів

Tags: вибір-слова

Як правильно:

1. Лимони - це кислі фрукти
2. Лимони - це кислий фрукт
3. Лимон - це кислі фрукти
4. Лимон - це кислий фрукт

Чи ці вирази взаємозамінні?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно:

> *Лимони — це кислі фрукти.
>
>   Лимон — це кислий фрукт.*

Щодо взаємозамінності:

- В більшості випадків, особливо для енциклопедій, є взаємозамінними.
- Коли важливий контекст (наприклад, тільки цей лимон) не є взаємозамінними.

---

> <sup>[Український правопис ¬ § 121. Тире (—)](http://pravopys.net/sections/121/)</sup>
>   3. Перед **це (це є)**, **оце**, **то**, **ось (це) значить**, якщо присудок, виражений іменником у називному відмінку або неозначеною формою дієслова, приєднується за допомогою цих слів до підмета:
>
> - *Гетьман, може, як ніхто інший знав, що любити Україну —  це найперше захистити її надійно від усіх ворогів* (Лупій).
> - *Класична пластика і контур строгий,
>
>     І логіки залізна течія —
>
>     Оце твоя, поезіє, дорога* (Зеров).
> - *Зернина —  то життя у сповитку* (Кащук).
> - *Серце чисте співця —
>
>     То ранкової відблиск роси* (Ющенко).
> - *Гармонійне злиття ідеї з художньою формою, в яку вона обрана, —  ось формула ідеального твору мистецтва* (Дрозд).
> - *Жити мені без праці —  значить не жити* (Павличко).

Цебто структура *„слово-тема — опис до нього“*;
Тому наступні (інші) варіанти неправильні, бо опис є неузгодженим до підмета:

> Лимони — це кислий фрукт.
>   Лимон — це кислі фрукти.

Подібне можна використовувати коли є:

Метафора чи на штиб цього

> *Сміле слово —  то наші гармати,
>
>   Світлі вчинки —  то наші мечі* (Грабовський).

Іменник підмета має лише множину чи однину

> *[Двері](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) — щитова конструкція та її облаштунки (коробка), що перекриває чи звільняє отвір в стіні, який використовується для проходу (входу — виходу)* [(Вікіпедія)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96).

---

Ну й (необовʼязковий) типографічний нюанс: [дефіс](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%84%D1%96%D1%81) й [тире](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5).

Comment: Я б ще додав, що «лимони — це кислий фрукт» та «лимон — це кислі фрукти» неузгоджені і в загальному випадку так не кажуть (хіба що у випадках, коли назва фрукта має лише однину/множину).

Comment: Слушне зауваження, бо це краще за „подібним чином“.

Comment: Дякую за відповідь! От мені вдалося знайти [твердження](http://pidruchniki.com/1031020840573/dokumentoznavstvo/zvyazok_prisudka_pidmetom) про узгодження в числі підмета з присудком, але в прикладах тільки дієслівні, а іменних нема.

Comment: @ata_zh, чесно кажучи, не знаю, де можна знайти підтвердження для цього. По-моєму, це банальна логіка: в лівій і правій частині має бути те, що ми співставляємо. У випадку «сміле слово — то наші гармати» ми кажемо що сміливе слово виконує таку роль, як гармати в війську (а не одна гармата; інакше можна було сказати «сміле слово — то наша артилерія»). Але у випадку фруктів, ІМХО, немає сенсу робити зіставлення одного до багатьох (чи багатьох до одного); хіба що у випадку граматичної обмеженості слова («пліснява — то грибок, дріжжі — то грибок»).